# Hard-coded image not displaying in wordpress footer

Tags: php, wordpress, footer

I finished a project using the Finesse Wordpress theme from Ixtendo several months ago and all was well. However, recently I've noticed that an image that is hard-coded in to footer.php no longer displays, instead all I see is the alt text.

I've also tried using the image as a background image to a div which doesn't work either.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Some further info in case it's useful. I had also hard-coded references to JS files in header.php which worked for a few months but then the theme stopped getting the links. I resolved this by installing a plugin called WP Headmaster which enqueues the JS in to the theme.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple answer in the end.

We have a hosting account, e.g myhosting.com. The Wordpress site is loaded in to a directory called 'abc' within the main hosting account.

There is a domain name pointing at this directory, e.g. mydomain.com. The problem came from me using myhosting.com/abc/images/logo.jpg when I should have been using mydomain.com/images/logo.jpg

I obtained the correct URL via the media manager in Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

This will most likely be that the image location is specified relatively.
If you copied the location from the css file, the relative location will probably not have been changed.

You can verify this by right clicking on the image in google chrome/other capable browser, and selecting "open image in new tab". There you will see the absolute URL - which is probably incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've used the full URL to the image location, I should have added that to my original post.

Comment: If the URL is correct and the image loads, we'll really need to see the page or the source to understand what's going on.

Comment: We have a hosting account, e.g myhosting.com. The Wordpress site is loaded in to a directory called 'abc' within the main hosting account. There is a domain name pointing at this directory, e.g. mydomain.com.

The problem came from me using myhosting.com/abc/images/logo.jpg when I should have been using mydomain.com/images/logo.jpg

I obtained the correct URL via the media manager in Wordpress.